# Content Search Web part not working properly for integer type of managed property

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-property, crawled-property, cswp

I have Site Column of type Number, Sharepoint Default created a managed property in Text type, So I created a custom managed property in the type of integer and mapped to that crawled property. CSWP retrieving the items only for `**MYCustomNumberMangedProperty = 0**` but it is not showing any items for the following query `**MYCustomNumberMangedProperty > 0**` or `**MYCustomNumberMangedProperty = 1**`. In our custom list we have 10 items, I don't understand why this behaving like that, Correct me If I am Wrong?

Comment: can you map it `RefinableInt` or `RefinableDouble` and then check ?

Comment: Thank GautamSheth ,I will check

Comment: ya, It's working for RefinableDouble.Thanks @GautamSheth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the site column of type `number` to either `RefinableIntxx` or `RefinableDouble` OOTB managed property.

Once your crawled property is mapped to either of these managed property, you will be able to perform comparison operations on it since number can contain values including decimal.